# How to create a vue component dynamically

Tags: vue.js

I've created a component in my vue instance.

```
components: {
        plan: {
            template: "#suggested-properties",
            props: ['plan', 'active'],
            computed: {
                isActive: function(){
                    return this.plan.name == this.active.name;
                }
            },
            methods: {
                setActivePlan: function(){
                    var that = this;
                    that.activeParameter= true;
                    this.active = this.plan;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Is there a way I can dynamically create an instance of the same components by passing data when I click on a button?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hopefully I understood your question currectly you just need to iterate through an array or so.

```
data: {
  numOfComps: 0
}
```

and in your HTML:

```
<component v-for="comp in numOfComps></component>
```

check the fiddle for an working example:

http://jsfiddle.net/gc2t8o5t/

Comment: Do you know any way to pass a :prop JSON object to such created component?

Comment: @kyeno you can add the prop like in any other component

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution if you do not know the name of the component beforehand

```
<component v-for="comp in arrayOfCompsString" :is="comp"></component>
```

Would replace the entire markup correctly